# Update to submodule in ADO repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

I have 2 ADO repositories - Repo1 & Repo2

Repo1 is set as a submodule in Repo2

Let's say I made a change in Repo1 and a new commit is added to 'master' branch in Repo1.

I ran the following commands to get that commit in the submodule in Repo2.

```
git submodule update --remote –merge
git add *
git status
git commit -m “updated public submodule”
```

Should I add a new commit in Repo2 each time when there is a new commit in Repo1 in order to update the submodule?

Answer (score 0):

No. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

When use Git Submodules, you can treat it as a normal git repo. When you clone a project with a submodule in it, by default you get the directories that contain submodules, but none of the files within them yet. You must run two commands: `git submodule init` to initialize your local configuration file, and `git submodule update` to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

```
git clone https://xxxxxx
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

More details please refer to the documentation below:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Thank you! So, after running the above git commands in my superproject, I see the latest commit # in the submodule. My question - let's say a new commit is added to Repo1 (remember Repo1 is set as submodule in Repo2). To see this new commit # in the submodule, I ran "git submodule update --remote –merge" and "git commit -m “updated commit # in submodule” in my superproject. This added new commit # in the submodule. Should I add a new commit in superproject each time when there is a new commit in Repo1 in order to update the submodule with latest commit #?

Comment: You could check the documentation https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules. The scenario to use Submodules is you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be able to use one from within the other. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.